# SetHighlighted gets called on touch up instead of touch down

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

What can cause `setHighlighted:animated:` to be called on touch up instead of touch down? I have a very slim subclassed `UITableViewCell`, only consisting of the following methods:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib

- (void)updateWithStuff:(NSString *)stuff

- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated
```

But `setHighlighted:animated:` gets called on touch up instead of touch down.
I have tried setting

```
self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

as well as

```
self.tableView.delaysContentTouches = NO;
```

The [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623280-sethighlighted?language=objc) doesn't say anything about exactly when setHighlighted is called, but a handful of Stackoverflow answers seem to agree that it is first called at touch down, and that `setHighlighted:animated:` is called later on.

Is my information incorrect, and is there a new/better way of getting touch down events in a cell?

**EDIT:**

I have tried removing any UIGestureRecognizers relevant to the view.
I also tried using a default UITableViewCell and using the default selection style, and I get the same results. It highlights as you release.

Comment: I believe that's how it works. In iOS actions are usually triggered on touch up, not touch down. A select action is likely the same.

Comment: @DuncanC In this demo, however, it works as I expect it to work (setHighlighted gets called on touch down). https://github.com/hossamghareeb/Facebook-POP-Tutorial

Comment: Incorrect: it gets called on both.

Answer (score 0):

> setHighlighted gets called on touch up instead of touch down

Actually, it gets called on both:

- on touch down with `highlighted` = `true`
- on touch up with `highlighted` = `false`

Additionally, fresh cells are being sent `setHighlighted` with `highlighted` = `false` upon display. See the timing of the messages in the animation below:

[image: 2 distinct highlighted]
[↻ replay animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8MoJ.gif)

Are you calling `super`?

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    var row = 0

    override func setHighlighted(_ highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setHighlighted(highlighted, animated: animated)
        print("setHighlighted row \(1+row): \(highlighted) animated: \(animated)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, but the problem remains. It seems as though both calls, true and false, happen on touch up. Nothing on touch down

Comment: Would it help if I posted a sample project?

Comment: Not really, I already have a sample project posted above, in which it works as expected. I'm just looking for reasons for why it would not work as expected, as I cannot post all of my code

Comment: Haven't I have shown that `setHighlighted` gets invoked at both touchdown and touchup?

Comment: You have, and I know that that is how it is supposed to work. But as I have tried to explain, it only gets called on touch up in my case. Not touch down. Which is my issue.